# Jquery delay mouse out

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, settimeout

I have this script:

```
$("#menu ul li").mouseover(
    function () {
        $(this).find(".submenu").fadeIn("slow");
    }
);

var timer = 0;
function animate_me() {
    $(this).find(".submenu").stop().fadeOut("slow");
}
$(function(){
    $("#menu ul li").mouseout(function(){
        timer = setTimeout("animate_me()", 300); // start timer when mouse is moved in
    }, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer); // stop it if mouse is moved out
    });
});
```

How do i delay the fadeout until menu ul li has been moused off for two seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all, mouseout, takes only one parameter. You need to use `.hover()` if you want to use it this way. Then you could just use `.dealy()` to achieve your goal, `.stop(true,true)` clears that delay

here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/zTTFJ/

Comment: Delay only delays the fadeout - i need it to stop the function if moused back over

Comment: if you use true on the true as first argument on `.stop()` it stops the delay also... try the demo...

Answer (score 3):

Use the **[HoverIntent plugin for jQuery](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)**. It does exactly what you need and more.

Specifically the timeout feature provides this capability. Example usage:

```
function showIt() { $(this).find(".submenu").fadeIn("slow"); }
function hideIt() { $(this).find(".submenu").stop().fadeOut("slow"); }

$("#menu ul li").hoverIntent({
    over: showIt,
    out: hideIt,
    timeout: 300 /*ms*/
});
```

From the documentation

> **timeout**:
>
> A simple delay, in milliseconds, before the "out" function is called.
>   If the user mouses back over the element before the timeout has
>   expired the "out" function will not be called (nor will the "over"
>   function be called). This is primarily to protect against sloppy/human
>   mousing trajectories that temporarily (and unintentionally) take the
>   user off of the target element... giving them time to return. Default
>   timeout: 0

Comment: its a nice comment, but is it an answer?